# eagerloading expand() function in angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I want the eagarloading expand function of breezejs to give me simple json objects when querying breeze's asp.net web api , so that i can iterate  it in my angular views. like {{p.users.projects.projectname}} .. but results i get is not plain json when digging deep inside projects

```
 function getUsersPartials() {

        return EntityQuery.from('users').expand('projects')
        .using(manager).execute()
        .to$q(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            users = data.results;
            console.log(users);
            log('Retrived [Users Partials] from remote data source ', users.length, true);
            return users;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .noTracking() on the query in order to get a simple json object